# Cannot use a second monitor

Tags: 12.04, ati, display

When I plug in my second display and activate it in "Displays" I get an "Out of range" error. It says the max desktop size is 1600 by 1600. Does anyone know a fix?
I have an AMD/ATI Mobility chipset, and the propriety drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've just found a solution. Firstly, enter this command:

```
mv ~/.config/monitors.xml ~/.config/monitors.xml.backup
```

You also need to edit your `Xorg` config and make the virtual desktop `4096 by 4096`:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Afterwards it should look like this

```
 SubSection "Display"
        Virtual         4096 4096
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
EndSubSection
```

Once you reboot you should be able to use the default display tool or amdcccle to configure it.